# Find the area of a triangle $\triangle FGH$

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, median

In triangle $\triangle FGH$, $GM$ is a median that lies on $4x-y=27$; height $HA$ lies on $x-y+3=0$; $F$ is $(4,5)$. Find the area of the triangle $\triangle FGH$.
My attempt:
F is not on any of the lines. Intersection of the lines (10,13). Then, i struggle.

Comment: This is correct 4x-7=27??

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence.  Any of *which* lines?

Comment: Is there a question here, or just a story of someone who took an exam?

Comment: Well, could you give some insight on how to solve this question?

Comment: @PavelFedotov: Not unless you take the time to proofread your question, and to indicate what you might have tried so that we can better tune our answers to your level of understanding. I'm guessing that English is not your first language, in which case you're doing pretty well, but MSE questions posed as commands to the folks you're asking for help...well, they tend to not be received all that well. Just a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GF$\perp$HA, the slope of GF is $-\frac14$ and GF lies on $4y+x-24 =0$. G is the intersection of GF and GM, which is $G(\frac{12}5,\frac{27}5)$.

Let $H(a,4a-27)$. Then, the midpoint is $M(\frac {a+4}2, \frac{4a-22}2)$ and it satisfies $x-y+3=0$, or

$$\frac {a+4}2-\frac{4a-22}2+3=0
$$

which yields $a=\frac{32}3$ and $H(\frac{32}3, \frac{47}3)$. With the coordinates of $F,G,H$ known, the area is given by the formula below

$$Area = \frac12| x_F(y_G-y_H)+ x_G(y_H-y_F)+ x_H(y_F-y_G)|
$$

Comment: Thank you, you made it look easy

Comment: I am not sure, i think you considered HA on 4x-y=27. Solution is very helpful.

Comment: @PavelFedotov - right. The steps are the same, though